# How to save image in laravel storage directory

Tags: php, laravel, base64, laravel-7, intervention

I need to save the image which was converted using base64 to the storage directory instead of saving it inside the `public` folder,

Here is my store function which saves the image into my `public` directory,

```
public function store(Request $request, Category $category)
{
    if ($request->image) {
        $name = time().'.'. explode('/', explode(':',substr($request->image, 0, strpos($request->image, ';')))[1])[1];

        Image::make($request->image)->save(public_path('img/category/').$name);

    return response('success');
}
```

I need to know how i can save the images into my storage folder,

Comment: Did you run php artisan storage:link?

Comment: @TariqImtinan yes i did, i need to know how to write the function to save the data to the storage directory, the above code saves the file to the public/img/category directory

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [Laravel 8 official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-local-driver), on my local laravel installation, I have imported the following:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

And then in the store method:

```
Storage::disk('local')->put(time() . '.' . 'example.txt', 'Contents');
```

It stores the file into storage/app and not into the public directory.